# Como pegar a posição da barra de rolagem com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho a seguinte página:

```
<style>
    navbar {
        color: #FFF;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    section {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    #sec-1 {
        background-color: red;
    }

    #sec-2 {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #sec-3 {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>

<navbar>
    <a href="">Link 1</a>
    <a href="">Link 2</a>
    <a href="">Link 3</a>
</navbar>

<section id="sec-1"></section>
<section id="sec-2"></section>
<section id="sec-3"></section>
```

Dependendo da seção que o scroll da página estiver, eu gostaria de trocar a cor da barra de navegação, como eu poderia fazer isso de maneira simples com JavaScript?

Comment: Poderia nos fornecer um [mcve] demostrando o esta tentando fazer.

Comment: Teste no console do seu navegador o comando `this.scrollY`

Comment: @AugustoVasques coloquei.

Comment: @BrennoSegolim mas o this deve referenciar qual elemento?

Comment: Referencia ao elemento `window`, tanto que se você digitar `window.scrollY` seria a mesma coisa. Até melhor usar `window.scrollY`, pois se você utilizar `this` dentro do contexto de uma classe, ela que será referida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O algorítimo é simples no evento [`window.scroll`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) ele faz um conjunto de verificações para saber sobre qual elemento o `<navbar>` está:

- verifica se `<navbar>` esta sobre `#sec-1` se estiver muda a cor do `<navbar>` para vermelho e abandona o evento.
- verifica se `<navbar>` esta sobre `#sec-2` se estiver muda a cor do `<navbar>` para verde e abandona o evento.
- verifica se `<navbar>` esta sobre `#sec-3` se estiver muda a cor do `<navbar>` para azule abandona o evento.
- caso não esteja sobre nenhum `<navbar>` muda a cor para preto.

Primeiro são calculados os valores iniciais de topo e base para cada `<section>` e `<navbar>` utilizando para isso princípios básicos de geometria([topo](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) mais a [altura](https://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) do elemento é igual a posição da base).

Já dentro do evento [`window.scroll`](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) os valores de topo e base são recalculados com relação a [rolagem da tela](https://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) e esses valores são comparados apenas com a base do  pois podemos saber sobre qual `<section>` ele está.

```js
//Calcula os valores estáticos de topo e base para os elementos <section>
let sec1Top = $("#sec-1").offset().top
let sec1Botton = sec1Top + $("#sec-1").outerHeight()
let sec2Top = $("#sec-2").offset().top
let sec2Botton = sec2Top + $("#sec-2").outerHeight()
let sec3Top = $("#sec-3").offset().top
let sec3Botton = sec3Top + $("#sec-3").outerHeight()

//Calcula os valos estático de base para o elemento <navbar>({top: 0; position: fixed;})
let navHeight = $("navbar").outerHeight()


//No evento scroll da janela
$(window).scroll(function() {

  // o número de pixels rolados na janela
  let wst = $(window).scrollTop();

  // Calcula os valores dinâmicos de topo e base para os elementos <section> com relação o número de pixels rolados a janela
  let s1T = sec1Top - wst
  let s1B = sec1Botton - wst
  let s2T = sec2Top - wst
  let s2B = sec2Botton - wst
  let s3T = sec3Top - wst
  let s3B = sec3Botton - wst

  //Se a base do <navbar> estiver sobre #sec1 
  if (navHeight > s1T && navHeight < s1B) {
    $("navbar").css('background-color', 'red');
    return;
  }

  //Se a base do <navbar> estiver sobre #sec2 
  if (navHeight > s2T && navHeight < s2B) {
    $("navbar").css('background-color', 'blue');
    return;
  }

  //Se a base do <navbar> estiver sobre #sec3
  if (navHeight > s3T && navHeight < s3B) {
    $("navbar").css('background-color', 'green');
    return;
  }

  //Se a base do <navbar> não estiver sobre nenhum <section>  
  $("navbar").css('background-color', 'black');

});

//Recalcula os valores estáticos de topo e base para os elementos <section> e <navbar> caso a janela do navegador seja redimensionada
$(window).resize(function() {
  sec1Top = $("#sec-1").offset().top
  sec1Botton = sec1Top + $("#sec-1").outerHeight()
  sec2Top = $("#sec-2").offset().top
  sec2Botton = sec2Top + $("#sec-2").outerHeight()
  sec3Top = $("#sec-3").offset().top
  sec3Botton = sec3Top + $("#sec-3").outerHeight()
})
```

```css
navbar {
  color: #FFF;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #000;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#sec-1 {
  background-color: red;
  /* Inseri uma margem para melhorar a visualização do resultado do algorítimo*/
  margin-top: 61px;
}

#sec-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#sec-3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<navbar>
  <a href="">Link 1</a>
  <a href="">Link 2</a>
  <a href="">Link 3</a>
</navbar>

<section id="sec-1"></section>
<section id="sec-2"></section>
<section id="sec-3"></section>
```